# How can I fetch Mysql data in 52 weeks format?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've hour table with following data

```
  Id  | user_id | login_date | hours
   1  |  123    | 01-01-2017 |   8
   2  |  123    | 02-01-2017 |   6
   .  |  ...    | .......... |   .
   .  |  ...    | .......... |   .
   .  |  123    | 31-12-2017  |  7
```

When I pick user and date range from dropdown, Is there anyway in mysql that I can fetch data in following way?

```
  Id  | week_No | total_hours
   1  |  1      |  40
   2  |  2      |  30
   .  |  ...    | 
   .  |  ...    | 
   .  |  52     |  38
```

I've tried using PHP looping but it queries in database about 52 times. Is there any other way I can fetch data table directly from mysql in mentioned way, So that we can save processing time.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: it would be nice if you could give sample query!

Comment: It would be nice to see some proper data. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution.

```
SELECT (select @rownum := @rownum + 1 from ( select @rownum := 0 ) d2 ) as rownumber, 
WEEKOFYEAR(login_date) as w, SUM(final_total) as final FROM `login_table` 
WHERE login_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' AND user_id = 470 AND 
organisation_id = 191 GROUP BY WEEK(login_date) ORDER BY rownumber
```

Answer (score 3):

Use also need to use the function WEEK to generate a week number from a date or datetime datatype.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   id
 , WEEK(login_date) AS week_No
 , SUM(hours) AS hours 
FROM 
 [table]
GROUP BY
   id
 , WEEK(login_date)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've tried this query : SELECT WEEK(login_date) AS week_No, id, SUM(hours) AS hours FROM login_hours WHERE user_id = 470 AND login_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' GROUP BY id, WEEK(login_date) ORDER BY `login_date`... it is returning all the rows with week number insted of 52 rows

Answer (score 1):

Use WEEK() function:

```
SELECT WEEK('01-01-2017');
```

[MySql WEEK()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php)